# italic symbols in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get the gamma symbol to be italicised in a plot label but can't figure out how to do it?

I thought this should work (but doesn't)

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\mathit{\Gamma}$$^{*}$')
```

I should add I am using the Helvetica font, so don't want to switch into tex mode, e.g. this doesn't work for me:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['font.family'] = "sans-serif"
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = "Helvetica"
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.plot(range(5), range(5))
plt.title('$\Gamma + \mathit{\Gamma}$', fontsize=40)
plt.show()
```

thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 23):

Write the text between '$$' that forces the text to be interpreted.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(5), range(5))
plt.title('$\it{text you want to show in italics}$')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Homayoun. I have a problem, when I'm using your method. My text goes italic but font changes, and isn't Times New Roman anymore. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Hi @CroSimpson2.0, I think your problem may be solved by setting `plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False` (which is the default). Matplotlib then uses [it's own TeX-like parsing](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html) and should not switch fonts.

Answer (score 6):

You should set `usetex = True`. See [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rc('text', usetex = True)

plt.plot(range(5), range(5))
plt.title('$\Gamma + \mathit{\Gamma}$', fontsize=40)
plt.show()
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: I don't want to switch into tex mode as I'm using the Helvetica font. I've edited my question above (thanks though).

Comment: Nothing really prevents you from using Helvetica in TeX. Add `\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}`, `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble (`pgf.preamble` field in `matplotlib`'s `rcParams`).

Comment: The `matplotlib.rc('text', usetext = True)` does not work for me. I believe we should also install some LaTeX related packages using `pip`? What would be the packages?

Answer (score -1):

One solution I've found:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['font.family'] = "sans-serif"
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = "Helvetica"
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False
plt.plot(range(5), range(5))
plt.title(u'${\u0413}$', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```