# How to avoid font change when writing a label in Italics with matplotlib?

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, fonts

The font is changed with:

```
import os
from matplotlib import font_manager as fm, rcParams
fpath = os.path.join(rcParams["datapath"], '/gdrive/My Drive/animal/data/times-new-roman.ttf')
prop = fm.FontProperties(fname=fpath,size=17)
```

I am concatenating my text labels as follows:

`label = $\it{'+ text + '}$` from [italic symbols in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470137/italic-symbols-in-matplotlib)

However Times new roman disappears everywhere italics appear. It happens in the following plot with the `xtick_labels`, but has happened with `ax.annotate()` and `ax.legend()`

[image]

Comment: rather than using latex, i would set the `fontstyle` to "italic" directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that using latex like you have is causing the font to fallback to the mathfont.

You can set the typeface and other font properties directly with latex:

```py
## -------- figure setup
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import ticker
x_vals = {0: 'This', 1: 'That', 2: 'The Other'}
y_vals = {0: 'They', 1: 'Them', 2: 'Everyone Else'}

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 2.5)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 2.5)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: x_vals.get(x, '')))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: y_vals.get(x, '')))

ax.tick_params('x', labelrotation=45)

## ------ WHERE PROPERTIES GET SET
for t in ax.get_xticklabels():
    t.set_fontstyle('italic')
    
for t in ax.get_yticklabels():
    t.set_fontweight('heavy')
```

[image]