# How to italicize a string with underscore in the title of a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to title a chart in seaborn as -

> countplot of *adult_male* by *alive*

I found an old Jupyter Notebook document where someone used `$` to wrap around the word to italicize. However, this does not work if there is an underscore. See the code below -

```
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

feature = "adult_male"
hue = "alive"

ax = sns.countplot(data=titanic, x=feature);
ax.set_title(f"countplot of ${feature}$ by ${hue}$");
```

How do I fix the title?

[image]

Comment: `$...$` is used to enter *math* mode, where an underscore is the subscript operator and variable names are italicized. It should *not* be used simply to italicize arbitrary text.

Comment: try this adding a back slash (\) before the underscore, it's a wild guess, haven't tested it

Comment: I'm not familiar with `seaborn`, but I assume it either uses behind the scenes or is inspired by `gnuplot`, which allowed (more or less) arbitrary LaTeX code for formatting text.

Comment: Even if you update the column name to not have `_`, italics don't work with spaces either. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT1ni.png)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470137/italic-symbols-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in a Jupyter Notebook document and a Python console.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(rc={"figure.dpi":300, 'savefig.dpi':300})

def esc(s):
    return s.replace("_", "\_")

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
feature = "adult_male"
hue = "alive"

ax = sns.countplot(data=titanic, x=feature);
ax.set_title(f"countplot of ${{{esc(feature)}}}$ by ${{{esc(hue)}}}$");

plt.show()
```

---

As [Trenton kindly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72902450/how-to-italicize-a-string-with-underscore-in-the-title-of-a-plot#comment128766565_72902450), using an [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to italicize doesn't work when plotting.

```py
def ital(s):
    return "\033[3m" + s + "\033[0m"

feature = "adult_male"
hue = "alive"
print(f"countplot of {ital(feature)} by {ital(hue)}")
```

The above works.

```py
def ital(s):
    return "\033[3m" + s + "\033[0m"

feature = "adult_male"
hue = "alive"
ax = sns.countplot(data=titanic, x=feature);
ax.set_title(f"countplot of {ital(feature)} by {ital(hue)}");
```

This doesn't.